# If D$f(0)\neq 0$ then I need to show that a change of variable exists

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I don´t know how to start this problem. Could someone help me please?

Let $f$ : $\mathbb {R}^N$ $\to$ $\mathbb {R}$  and $f$ is a function of class $C^1$ in $\mathbb {R}^N$. Suppose D$f(0) \neq 0$, then I need to show that a change of variable $\varphi$ : $\mathbb {R}^N$ $\to$ $\mathbb {R}^N$ exists such that:

$\varphi(0)= 0$, D$\varphi(0)$ is the identity.

$f(\varphi(x)) = f(0) + Df(0)\cdot$ x,  for a small x

Comment: You are saying that $Df(0)=0$ so the last equation becones $f(\phi(x))=f(0)$. This is not possible with $D\phi(0)=$ identity.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, already edit it. Thank you

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? Is it $\mathbb R^{n}$ or $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is $\mathbb {R}^N$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function 
$$\psi(x):=Df(0)^{-1}(f(x)-f(0)).$$

We have $\psi(0)=0 $, and $D\psi(0)=\mathrm{Id}$. By the inverse function theorem, $\psi$ has a $\mathcal{C}^1$ inverse map $\phi$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Then $$f(x)=f(0)+Df(0)\psi(x)\Rightarrow f(\phi(x))=f(0)+Df(0)x $$
near $0$ as required.

(Technically, we have only constructed the change of variable near $0$, but we can extend it arbitrarily whilst preserving the desired properties.)

Answer (score 0):

By changing order of basis vectors we can assume, that
$$
Df(0)=(f_1(0), f_2(0),\dots, f_n(0)) \text{ with } f_1(0) = a \neq 0
$$

Let $\varphi^{-1}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)=(f(x)/a-f(0)/a-\sum_{i=2}^n (f_i(0)x_i/a), x_2, \dots, x_n)$. So it is easy to check, that $D\varphi(0) = id$ and $f(\varphi(x))=f(0)+ax_1+\sum_{i=2}^n (f_i(0)x_i/a).$ Notice, that $\varphi$ is defined locally and the definition is legal by inverse function theorem.